# How to get an index of specific text in dropdown using vbscript code(.vbs)?

Tags: vbscript

I am working on vbscript. I am writing script for selecting value from dropdown.
In my scenario, I want to select a value from dropdown using the text which resides in option tag i.e `<option>value<option>`

Request you to provide code for selecting value in dropdown using value not by index of value.

Thank you in advance. Please reffer below html code for reference.

```
<select id="mydropdown" onchange="getServiceDetails();" name="mydropdown">
value="[]"
<option value="-1">Select value</option>
value="[]"
<option value="0920102049">value 1</option>
value="[]"
<option value="0060217015">value 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it.

```
Sub SelectOptionByInnerHTML(selectID, text)
    Dim list, opt
    Set list = document.getElementById(selectID)
    For Each opt In list
        If opt.innerHTML = text Then
            opt.selected = true
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next  
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
SelectOptionByInnerHTML "mydropdown", "value 2"
```